ClickUp API - value no longer available in custom field with formula
I am trying to get a list of tasks from ClickUp, using their API. One of the pieces of information that I need is the value in a custom field. It is a calculated value, using a formula inside ClickUp.
For several months the script that does that worked fine. The result of the API request included this calculated value in the "custom_fields". But now, the value is missing.
I used the Get Task endpoint in Postman, to make sure, and I get the same thing - there is the formula in "type_config", but no "value" field.
Here is how that particular field looks like in the response from ClickUp, in Postman:
{
            "id": "id………….",
            "name": "Cost",
            "type": "formula",
            "type_config": {
                "simple": false,
                "formula": "IF(SOME_FIELD=0,PRODUCT(CUSTOM_FIELD_11111,CUSTOM_FIELD_22222),product(SOME_FIELD,CUSTOM_FIELD_33333))",
                "version": "1.9",
                "reset_at": 17082866851,
                "is_dynamic": false,
                "return_types": [
                    "null",
                    "number"
                ],
                "calculation_state": "ready"
            },
            "date_created": "173838384670",
            "hide_from_guests": false,
            "required": false
        }

I noticed that another formular field, but which uses only standard fields, still shows the value.
Does anyone know if ClickUp made changes to the API and if there is still a way to get that calculated value or should I give up and just use the other fields to calculate it again in the script?
